# Setting up server behind uncontrolled firewall

Tags: networking, proxy, nat

(Firstly, I apologize if this is on the wrong site. I am not a network engineer or a web master or anything like that.)

Going off to college and my brother and I want to continue hosting a minecraft server for us and a few friends. The issue is that we host it on our desktops, which we will be bringing with us, and won't be staying at our parents' house.

I highly doubt that the university will allow us to forward ports or do any kind of router configuration (though I am willing to ask). I've read about two main kinds of work-arounds for this sort of thing:

1. Hole punching - use a third-party to basically coordinate your packet-sending so that they coincide and the router performing NAT thinks one of them is a response and that a connection has been made.
2. Proxy - that is, instead of having clients try to initiate a connection directly with the server, they initiate a connection with some other system whose internet connection we *do* control, which the server is also connected to. The proxy sends the data from the clients to the server, where special software sends it to the actual minecraft server program and redirects the output to the proxy. Basically having connections from a-> b and b -> c instead of a -> c, because port forwarding is required for an a->c connection.

There are, however, some issues which I seek advice for fixing with these approaches. My issue with the hole punching approach is that it firstly seems unreliable (for use with TCP traffic) and that it seems to require this approach to be built into the program itself - could this be achieved through use of iptables or something similar and an external program?

My issue with the proxy approach is that the only systems we have whose connections we control have very, very abysmal connections and absurdly restrictive data limits. Latency would be insane if all traffic had to go through it.

Do you have any way to improve these approaches / advice to contribute / explanation of things I seem to have misunderstood?